# I can't hide the subfolder in my redirected URL by the .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I saw some solutions here, but they didn't help me.
My index.php is here: `http://localhost/basic-2/web/index.php`.

And I would like to aim that If I type the `http://localhost/basic-2`, the browser redirect me to the `http://localhost/basic-2/web/index.php` path, but in the browser the URL be the `http://localhost/basic-2/index.php` address.
So I would like to remove (or hide) the `web` subfolder from the URL.

I have seen many solutions here... but nothing :(, Now I have this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /web/$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

But this is only list the folders and files... and not make redirect to the subfolder.

This can redirect, but doesn't hide the `web` folder from the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web [L]
```

**Edit1**
I found another rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1
```

This can redirect! But this rule doesn't hide(or remove) the `web` folder still...

Comment: Where are these rules? in the `basic-2` folder?

Comment: Yes, the rules (the .htaccess) is in the `basic-2` folder :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /basic-2/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/basic-2/web/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [P,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /basic-2/web/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /basic-2/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No, this gave me this error: _Not found_
`The requested URL /basic-2/index.php was not found on this server.
`

Comment: Now I go to sleep, I will come back after 12 hours.